# Missing libAnalyzer

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I am trying to build the analyzer using the Saleae SDK 1.1.19 but run into an error when running the python script. Not sure if it is because I am running a 64bit version of Ubuntu. I also could not find the ./lib/libAnalyzer.so

link to the analyzer that I am using
https://www.saleae.com/index

Error:

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../lib/libAnalyzer.so when searching for -lAnalyzer

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAnalyzer

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

g++ L"../lib" -lAnalyzer -shared -o"debug/libNSLogicAnalyzer.so" debug/NSLogicAnalyzer.o debug/NSLogicAnalyzerSettings.o debug/NSLogicAnalyzerResults.o

System information:
Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit,
Python 2.7.3

thanks!
LC

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out, it was calling the 32bit libAnalyzer.so in the lib folder. I just renamed the 64 bit to the same name as the 32bit (renamed the 32bit to something else so it would not create the error again)